# React Native Animated Loop start callback

Tags: react-native

I am struggling with React Native Animations here. The outcome is simple, I have an Animated.Image which I want to spin.
All good, until I want to loop thru the animation for n times and do something when it stops.
I have the following code .

```
Animated.loop(
  Animated.timing(this.state.spin, {
    toValue: 360,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }), {
    iterations: 3
  }
).start(() => {
  console.log('done');
});
```

It spins 3 times as per loop iteration but no callback was fired when animation ends.

Here the Expo which replicates this: https://snack.expo.io/S1PjnfB9-

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below

```
Animated.loop(
  Animated.timing(this.state.spin, {
    toValue: 360,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }), {
    iterations: 3
  }
).start(event => {
    if (event.finished) {
      console.log('finished');
    }
  });
```

I just added a check on the event response.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope... Still does`t work. The callback function is not called on end event.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.
It seems that if you take out `useNativeDriver` it works as it should be, and the callback is called.
This is weird...

Comment: I am encounting a situation at where after I add one line : userNativeDriver :true, the Callback will be called once.